# How to divide group depend on idx, diff in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

There is my dataset. I want to make group numbers depending on `idx`, `diff`. Exactly, I want to make the same number until `diff` over 14 days. It means that if the same `idx`, under `diff` 14 days, it should be the same group. But if they have the same idx, over 14 days, it should be different group.

```
idx = c("a","a","a","a","b","b","b","c","c","c","c")
date = c(20201115, 20201116, 20201117, 20201105, 20201107, 20201110, 20210113, 20160930, 20160504, 20160913, 20160927)
group = c("1","1","1","1","2","2","3","4","5","6","6")
df = data.frame(idx,date,group)
df <- df %>% arrange(idx,date)
df$date <- as.Date(as.character(df$date), format='%Y%m%d')
df <- df %>% group_by(idx) %>% 
  mutate(diff = date - lag(date))
```

This is the result of what I want.
[image]

Comment: Hi, if any answers have solved your question, you could accept one of them you prefer by clicking the check-mark. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use `cumsum` to create another group criteria, and then `cur_group_id()`.

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(idx) %>% 
  mutate(diff = difftime(date, lag(date, default = first(date)), unit = "days"),
         cu = cumsum(diff >= 14)) %>% 
  group_by(idx, cu) %>% 
  mutate(group = cur_group_id()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  select(-cu)
```

```r
# A tibble: 11 × 4
   idx   date       group diff    
   <chr> <date>     <int> <drtn>  
 1 a     2020-11-05     1   0 days
 2 a     2020-11-15     1  10 days
 3 a     2020-11-16     1   1 days
 4 a     2020-11-17     1   1 days
 5 b     2020-11-07     2   0 days
 6 b     2020-11-10     2   3 days
 7 b     2021-01-13     3  64 days
 8 c     2016-05-04     4   0 days
 9 c     2016-09-13     5 132 days
10 c     2016-09-27     6  14 days
11 c     2016-09-30     6   3 days
```

Answer (score 1):

Given that the first value of `diff` must be `NA` because of the use of `lag()`, you could use `cumsum(diff >= 14 | is.na(diff)` without grouping to create the new group:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(idx) %>% 
  mutate(diff = date - lag(date)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(group = cumsum(diff >= 14 | is.na(diff)))

# # A tibble: 11 × 4
#    idx   date       diff     group
#    <chr> <date>     <drtn>   <int>
#  1 a     2020-11-05  NA days     1
#  2 a     2020-11-15  10 days     1
#  3 a     2020-11-16   1 days     1
#  4 a     2020-11-17   1 days     1
#  5 b     2020-11-07  NA days     2
#  6 b     2020-11-10   3 days     2
#  7 b     2021-01-13  64 days     3
#  8 c     2016-05-04  NA days     4
#  9 c     2016-09-13 132 days     5
# 10 c     2016-09-27  14 days     6
# 11 c     2016-09-30   3 days     6
```